# Flash AS2 Full Screen Image Scroller With Easing

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

Are there any tutorials out there that can teach me how to achieve the effect in AS2 as seen in the following site:

http://robertjaso.com/

The effect I am talking about is the scrolling image effect on mousemove with esing upon clicking on one of the tiled images...

I can't find help anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with Greensock's tweener?

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

They have a AS2 version of the "engine"